# Right approach to use container db for int testing in .net framework API

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, docker, .net-4.8

High-level context is I am working on Legacy app(.net framework) int tests that are periodically failing.
This is because test cleanup is removing test data from the actual database.

Some tables (linked with FKs) are so large (local machines) the delete is timing out.
The approach I have taken is to create a container holding the db with a minimal set of data.
If the int tests are run against the api using this docker database they now pass (and far quicker!).

The issue is we run int tests against the api hosted on a devs IIS. This means we need to change its connection string to point to docker. but when running locally we need it to point to localdb.
Due to old tech, it doesn't seem easy for the int tests to stand up their own in-memory api.

Approach tried

1. I tried containerising the API but as it is built into .NET framework and its a large and complex project with many dependencies faced many issues around creating it.
2. One person suggested having a specific web.config which could point to a different database
   Not sure how to proceed with 2nd approach.
   Really appreciate it if anyone can help me point me in the right direction.

Connection_strings picked up from octopus during deployment
[image]

We have used Dbcontext like below

```
public class InternalContext : DbContext
{
    public BloggingContext()
        : base("**InternalDatabase**")
    {
    }
}
```

and web.config look like this

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="**InternalDatabase**"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"
         connectionString="Data Source=Blogging.sdf"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Suggestion 2 is imo the easiest approach. In .net framework the web.config is a XML file. You can transform a xml file with a xslt file. In this xslt you put the connectionstring to the containerized database.
So what you have to do is to transform the web.config before you run the integration tests.

Comment: good question, but unfortunately way too broad for Stack. There's no correct way to do that, as this highly depends on too many factors to be listed in a single answer. Did you also consider to run docker locally in your dev-sceario? So that all your environments use docker for the db? Anyway you need to configure the connection-string somewhere.

Comment: So you basically want to switch the connection string from the local dev DB to a local (containerized) test DB? How are you making your app choose the correct connection string when you deploy it to prod?

Comment: @L01NL but this would required to re-publish/deploy the whole app. This might take long. I think a runtime switch would be easier during development.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride, it seems that they run the integration tests on a dev machine, since you can change the web.config without rebuilding the app, it would be an easy solution to create a batch file which transforms the web.config file, and back again when needed.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain I'm having trouble with the connection string because the API can't tell where the call originated, such as from a front-end application or an int test. So how can we distinguish between them and use different connection strings?

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride, we used environment vars on octopus which scoped to each environment and picked the connection strings accordingly

Comment: @L01NL I am not sure about the approach you suggested. Could you please share more details about it?

Comment: @DevSay so couldn't you just set the env var to the local/container DB and restart the app's IIS site?

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride could do that (configuration) but to run int tests locally would mean changing to config, rebuilding (which deploys to IIS). Then running int tests. changing configuration back to debug (or whatever) and rebuilding for local running.

Comment: Switching the connection string of the API based on client origin is a bad idea, because it forces you to mix test code with production code (`if (client == INTTEST) { useContainerDb(); } else { useNormalDb(); }`). I still don't understand how the app is choosing the connection string at runtime. From the config file? So the connection string is actually replaced with the correct value during deployment? What does this has to do with environment variables then? You need to go into more detail about your deployment process, because the answer depends on it.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride added connection strings for more details

Comment: XML transformation is rather common, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dd465326(v=vs.110) if you know how to properly use it.